# Dúvida - Projetar na tela secundária e Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Segue código do evento click:

```
//Estendido
telaSecundaria = new SegundaTela();
Screen[] telas = Screen.AllScreens;
Rectangle bounds = telas[1].Bounds; // pode ser outro índice.
telaSecundaria.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
telaSecundaria.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

telaSecundaria.Show();
telaSecundaria?.ChangeLabel(label1);
```

O código acima funciona ok (mostrando normal na tela secundária), como eu faço pegar o resultado da tela secundária e jogar no Form1 do `panel1` ?

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há varias formas de se fazer isso. A que imagino que seja mais fácil é passar para o seu novo Form um objeto do que você precisa utilizar no seu form1

```
//form1
Form2 form2 = new Form2(seuResultado);
if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // adicione o que você quer fazer com o objeto alterado no seu form1
    // ex:
    textBox1.Text = seuResultado.alteracoesQuePreciso;
}

//form2
SeuResultado seuResultado;
public Form2(SeuResultado seuResultado)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.seuResultado = seuResultado;
}
```

No seu form2 quando tiver terminado de modificar o `seuResultado` 
dentro do seu onClick do botão que você confirma que o resultado esta pronto para ser devolvido

```
seuResultado.alteracoesQuePreciso = TudoQuePrecisa;
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

E seu form2 se fechara o seuResultado vai estar pronto para ser utilizado no form1.

Dessa forma o seu `form1` ficara 'em espera' até que você finalize o seu `form2`

Se você precise deixar ambos os forms abertos e trabalhar com eles de forma simultanea, acho que a forma mais fácil é passar um delegate para o form2.

No form1 você adiciona no seu metodo de atualizar a checagem de InvokeRequired, para evitar problema com as Threads

```
public void Atualizar(SeuResultado seuResultado)
{
    if(InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() => Atualizar(seuResultado)));
        return;
    }
    textBox1.Text = seuResultado.alteracoesQuePreciso;
}

// para criar seu form2 você passa seu metodo de atualização como parametro
Form2 f = new Form2(Atualizar);
f.Show();
```

E o no `form2` você modifica o contrutor com um `delegate` para atualizar o form1

```
Action<SeuResultado> action;
public Form2(Action<SeuResultado> action)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.action = action;
}

public void EnviarAtualizacao()
{
    //SeuResultado res
    action(res);
}
```

Comment: Esse `SeuResultado` voce criou outro Form ?

Comment: Não, é um objeto contendo seu resultado